# How do you make a text clickable in jetpack compose ? I would also like to toggle it to non clickable after selecting once

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

This is my code:

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "Resend OTP",
    fontSize = 20.sp,
    color =  Textfieldcolor,
    style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)
)
```

I want the text to be clickable once and then disabled.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use a button (maybe a TextButton). It accepts both an `onClick` lambda as well as an `enabled` boolean.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add the [clickable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)) modifier to your [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.collections.Map,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) or use [ClickableText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#ClickableText(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) instead of [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.collections.Map,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)).

Here is an example of how to do it with [ClickableText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#ClickableText(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)):

```
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true)}

ClickableText(
    text = AnnotatedString(text) ,
    onClick = {
        if (enabled) {
            enabled = false
            text = "Disabled"
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi thank you ! I used this but looks like the text is clickable still after using once.Should I give an if for enabled's true and false states ?

Comment: @Shehar Sorry my bad. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you .I'm not sure if the clickability was disabled -I couldn't figure out from my emulator .But I addded corresponding toast messages to the corresponding states and they worked fine .

Comment: It doesn't have `color`, `textAlign` attributes.

Answer (score 10):

Like @Arpit mentioned it would be better to use a `TextButton` for this purpose.
But if you absolutely want to use `Text`, You can use following snippet.

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun OneTimeClickableText(text : String, onClick : () -> Unit){
    var enabled by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(true)}
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(enabled = enabled) {
                enabled = false
                onClick()
            },
        text = text
    )
}
```

That said I this code is strictly for one-time clickable text. I won't recommend using it for something like OTP button; as user won't be able to click it unless they restart your app. You can pull the `enabled` variable and manage it from outside(e.g. keeping it disabled for certain amount of time rather than permanently).

Comment: Hi thanks ! I decided to go with clickable text but  I can't seem to disable it even after setting enabled to false.I'll try with textbutton now.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to disable `ClickableText` (although I might be wrong here.) `TextButton` should work without any problem. Just be sure to pass `enabled` to the Button's `enabled` parameter.

Comment: It should be an accepted answer. It doesn't change a view (`Text`) and it's attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to make only part of the text clickable in a non-custom way:

```
val text = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("This is not clickable ")
    withAnnotation("tag", "annotation") {
        append("This is clickable")
    }
}

ClickableText(text) {
    text.getStringAnnotations(it, it).firstOrNull()?.tag?.let { tag ->
        // Check which tag was clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the accepted answer could be suit for most of your cases, but there are another options for more requirements:

`pointerInput` when you need long press double etc.

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                                    detectTapGestures(
                                        onPress = {
                                            println("on press")
                                        },
                                        onTap = {
                                            println("on tap")
                                        },
                                        onDoubleTap = {
                                            println("on double tap")
                                        },
                                        onLongPress = {
                                            println("on long press")
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
```

If you need to know the actions then use `pointerInteropFilter`

```
.pointerInteropFilter {
                                    when (it.action) {
                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                            println("action up")

                                        }

                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                            println("action Down")

                                        }

                                        else -> {}
                                    }
                                    true
                                }
```

And be ware when one of these `onClick` doesn't work.